# Prepared statement inside a prepared statement

Tags: php, loops, prepared-statement

I've been trying to get the id of each person rostered to a certain event. Which works.
However this for some reason doesn't work. When it did before. I realised while testing that when i put the $userRes->close right after the while($userRes->fetch()) the $user = getUser($connection, $id) works, but when it is outside the loop it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
$userQuery = "SELECT person_id FROM RosterPeopleEvent WHERE news_id=?;";
$userRes = $connection->prepare($userQuery);
$userRes->bind_param('i', $eventID);
$userRes->execute();
$userRes->bind_result($id);

while ($userRes->fetch()){
    $user = getUser($connection, $id);
    if ($user == $_SESSION["uid"]){
        $p->addContent("You have volunteered for the BBQ <a href=roster.php?rosterid=1&personid=$id&eventid=$eventID&class=remove rel=external>Remove</a>, ");  
    }
    else{
        $p->addContent("$user has volunteered for the BBQ <a href=roster.php?rosterid=1&personid=$id&eventid=$eventID&class=remove rel=external>Remove</a>, "); 
    }                           
}
$userRes->close();
```

Comment: For one thing, delete the 1st `;` in `WHERE news_id=?;";` such as `WHERE news_id=?";`

Comment: yeah that's just weird practice i have. But that wouldn't affect the way the loop works at all.

Comment: I've seen this problem happen with PDO.  The solution had something to do with closing the cursor: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php

Comment: Okay guys, i figured it out. All you need to do is: 
After the bind_result, add a $userRes->store_result();
And you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version:

```
$userQuery = "SELECT person_id FROM RosterPeopleEvent WHERE news_id=?;";
$userRes = $connection->prepare($userQuery);
$userRes->bind_param('i', $eventID);
$userRes->execute();
$userRes->bind_result($id);
$userRes->store_result();

while ($userRes->fetch()){
    $user = getUser($connection, $id);
    if ($user == $_SESSION["uid"]){
        $p->addContent("You have volunteered for the BBQ <a href=roster.php?rosterid=1&personid=$id&eventid=$eventID&class=remove rel=external>Remove</a>, ");  
    }
    else{
        $p->addContent("$user has volunteered for the BBQ <a href=roster.php?rosterid=1&personid=$id&eventid=$eventID&class=remove rel=external>Remove</a>, "); 
    }                           
}
$userRes->close();
```